# Python datetime to Azure Edm.DateTimeOffset

Tags: python, azure, datetime

How to convert a string of the format 2020-01-03 05:30:44.201000 to a date time offset aware string..

I am getting this value from a cosmosdb database and trying to insert the same into a search service.

Getting the error as

```
Cannot convert the literal '2020-01-08 11:49:41.653000' to the expected type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset'
```

I guess the output should be in the following format..

```
"2015-09-20T00:00:00Z"
```

I want to use python datetime but dont know how to to convert the string to format understandable for azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
s = "2020-01-03 05:30:44.201000"
dttm = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
dttm2 = dttm.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") # Prints "2020-01-03T05:30:44.201000Z"
print dttm2
```

Comment: except for the date and time separation character, what is the difference to simply appending the 'Z' character to the input string?

Comment: I believe you would need to put in the date/time separator character (`T`) as well. Simply appending `Z` is not going to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think so - 'T' or space should both be ISO8601 compatible. Btw. in the Azure docs, it's a space char.

Comment: @MrFuppes...Please see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations. As per this page, `T` is the separator. HTH.

Comment: if you follow the link to [RFC3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339), you'll find that "NOTE: ISO 8601 defines date and time separated by "T".
      Applications using this syntax may choose, for the sake of
      readability, to specify a full-date and full-time separated by
      (say) a space character."

Comment: ...and Azure is making use of that, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Appending the literal character 'Z' to signal UTC could be achieved very simply by `'2020-01-03 05:30:44.201000' + 'Z'` ('T' or space is both ISO format, so no need to change that).

However, the *correct* way I'd assume would be to convert to a timezone aware datetime object and then back to string. Using isoformat methods (Python 3.7+), that could look like

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dtobj = datetime.fromisoformat('2020-01-03 05:30:44.201000').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 5, 30, 44, 201000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

dtstr = dtobj.isoformat()
# '2020-01-03T05:30:44.201000+00:00'
```

Prerequisite is of course that the input string refers to UTC.